# Сохранение массива настроек из DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

У меня есть `DataGrid`. В этом `DataGrid` есть колонка с `toggleButton`

```
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Установлен" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsInstalled, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        </ToggleButton>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Я хочу сохранять состояние этих кнопок после закрытия программы. Пытался сохранять через `Properties.Settings.Default`, но тут получается массив, не совсем понимаю как это можно сделать?

Comment: М-м-м... При чём здесь wpf и datagrid? Ведь ваш вопрос заключается в том, как сохранить массив/список в настройках проекта.

Comment: Стандартным способом добавляете в настройки коллекцию, даёте ей желаемое имя. Всё, можно использовать. / Открыв файл Settings.Designer.cs можно изменить тип коллекции на любой подходящий.